# getting parameters from httppost in android to grails

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I am using the following code to convert json to StringEntity

```
   StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json,"UTF-8");
   se.setContentType("application/json");
   httpPost.setEntity(se);
```

at the server side. i am using grails. I am unable to parse the data. 
Say i have a controller : http://example.com/login
and login have following definition.

```
def login(params){
String email = params.email;
//validaton logic
}
```

it is unable to get the 'email' from post request. please anyone can guide me how to get the values.
I am passing two values in json objec i.e. email and password.

Comment: What does your `params` object contain if you `println` it? Does `request.JSON.email` contain your email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `request.JSON.email` since it's a JSON request.